# how to Combine TextViews in xml?

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to build this view in xml file in android that express a list item in a recyclerview

[image]

but I get this view instead

[image]

here's my code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_news"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_perm_identity_grey_400_48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_news_name"
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Mohamed Alaa"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_news_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="added a new photo to the album"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I improve my code to get the Desired result?

Please I want any answer to be applied in xml files only without writing java code

Comment: Why did you put the ImageView alone in a layout? That's really an anti-pattern. Try using a RelativeLayout, to combine alle yout Views in a unique container.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```java
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);

String name = "Mohammed Alaa";
String album = "Instagram Photos";

SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();

sb.append(name,new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
sb.append(" added a new photo to the album ");
sb.append(album,new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
sb.append(".");

tv.setText(sb);
```

Comment: how can i  join a list_item layout file like the one above to a java file??

Comment: Use LayoutInflater

Comment: `View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.yourLayout,null);`
This `View v` can be a LinearLayout.